# Variable size array from table

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to c++ and I would appreciate if someone could help solving following problem.

When I want to create an array (Arr) with variable size (S), I do in the following way:

```
const int S=10;
int Arr[S];
```

However, in the code I am trying to write, I need to choose S from a Table. Let say I have following table:

```
int Table[3]={11, 21, 31};
```

and I choose S from the table and define Arr

```
const int S=Table[0];
int Arr[S];
```

I cannot compile this code because I get an error that S must have a constant  have constant value.

I would appreciate any help/hint.

Comment: Remove "const" and make sure your compiler supports VLAs.

Comment: I don't think VLA are standard conform. Is it not only gcc (and maybe clang) which have it?

Comment: C++ does not have "arrays with variable size"; the size is part of the array *type*. You want `std::vector`.

Comment: variable sized arrays are called `std::vector` in C++

Comment: Make `Table` const as well, or `S` isn't truely const, which explains the error.

Comment: @awesomeyi:  S is truly const.  It isn't a compile time constant (but that is different).  I don't think `const Table[3] = {11,21,31};` will make `S` a compile time constant.  (But making `Table` const is a good idea regardless).

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem, you need to declare Table constexpr:

```
void foo() {
  const int S=10;
  int Arr[S];
  constexpr int Table[3]={11, 21, 31};
  constexpr int S2=Table[0];
  int Arr2[S2];
}
```

Explanation: by declaring Table `constexpr`, you let compiler know that it knows it contents at compile time. Now it can be used whenver literal constants can be used, including array sizes. I'have shown the use of intermediate `constexpr` variable to illustrate this effect better, but you could use `Table[0]` as `Arr2` size directly.

**NB**. `constexpr` is a keyword introduced in C++11, but I assume, it is safe to assume this dialect by default in 2016.

Comment: I wonder if the size the OP wants is actually statically known. I'd have guessed it was known only at run-time, but the question is not so clear in that aspect.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 and when I type constexpr, I get error. However, I have fixed the problem by defining vector instead of array. However, thank you very much for the answers